# Create a dictionary by extracting data from SQL. A value (list) is not extracted correctly

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary with values pulled from the database. Then create keys and values. It seems to do everything right except for the last value which is a small list of numbers eg `[0, 1, 1, 5]`. The Sql code is correct. It's a Python code problem

I would like to build the dictionary like this for example or something similar:

```
{'Minnesota-Dallas': ['NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', [0, 1, 1, 5],
```

but the problem is that they don't extract all the values in the list but only one, for example getting this:

```
{'Minnesota-Dallas': ['NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 5]
```

As you can see, the `5` is extracted, but not 0, 1, 1, 5.

The items pulled from the database are `row[0]` for the key, and then the values are `row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]`. The value I'm having trouble with (the one that should extract [0, 1, 1, 5]) is `row[5]`. Thank you!

I tried this code:

```
x = cursor_test.execute('''SELECT Next.team_home||"-"||Next.team_away,
                                            Next.championship, Next.date, Next.current_round, Next.clock,
                                            Results.score_home
                                     FROM Next
                                     INNER JOIN Results
                                     ON Next.team_home = Results.team_home;''')

    test = {}
    for row in x.fetchall():
         test[row[0]] = [row[i] for i in range(1, 6)]
```

---

A `print(row)` inside the loops shows:

```
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 0) 
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 1) 
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 1) 
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 5)
...
```

Comment: Can you share the table definition ? And share the output of a `select * from the_table` to ensure it contains what you expect ?

Comment: @azro It is a bit difficult because the table is very long. However I wrote the various row[] what they correspond to. With these you can solve the question

Comment: @azro Shared. Updated

Comment: add `print(row)` in your loop to ensure you have the data, then you'll if the issue if with SQL retrieving or your python code

Comment: @azro I've already tried print(row), otherwise it wouldn't make sense to ask the question. The problem occurs with Python code. The Sql code is correct

Comment: So share what the `print(row)` shows so, for some rows

Comment: @azro Did you read my question carefully? I have it in the question posted. I get this {'Minnesota-Dallas': ['NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 5]

Comment: Did you read my question carefully ? I asked for `row` not the `test` output. It seems you have failed  to store row data to test, so let me help, share the full `row` so I can see what you're missing in your python code

Comment: @azro Sorry. Communication problems. I'm using Google Translate. If I use print(row) inside the loop, I get: ('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 0) ('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 1) ('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 1) ('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 5) and other hockey matchs. If I use print(row) outside the loop, I get ONLY {'Vegas-Chicago': ['NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, regarding the output of `row`, you table doesn't contain a record

```
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', [0, 1, 1, 5])
```

But N records, for the N values if the list as the end

```
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 0) 
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 1) 
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 1) 
('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 5)
```

**If that isn't the format you want to store the data in, fix that** (and the code you have will work)

Improvement of your code if you fix the format

```py
test = {}
for row in x.fetchall():
    test[row[0]] = row[1:] # equivalent to row[1:6]

# or even better using unpacking
for key, *values in x.fetchall():
    test[key] = values
```

---

Solution for the actual data format

```py
test = {}
for row in x.fetchall():
    if row[0] not in test:
        test[row[0]] = list(row[1:])
        test[row[0]][4] = [test[row[0]][4]]  # transform int to list of int
    else:
        test[row[0]][4].append(row[5])
```

---

Something better would be to do it in 2 queries

```
x = cursor_test.execute('''SELECT team_home||"-"||team_away,
                           championship, date, current_round, clock,
                           FROM Next''')

test = {}
for row in x.fetchall():
     test[row[0]] = row[1:]
     q = cursor_test.execute("select score_home from Results where team_home = %s", row[0])
     results = [data[0] for data in q.fetchall()]
     test[row[0]].append(results)
```

Comment: When I use your second code, I get this error:     test[row[0]][5] = [test[row[0]][5]] # transform int to list of int
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Takao貴男 ah yes, see again I fixed it

Comment: I have two questions: 1. Is it necessary if row[0] not in test? Can't I use a setdefault (without setdefault if row[0] not in test:)? 2. Why did you insert the condition with the else?

Comment: @Takao貴男 the data is in a bad format, you need that code for it

Comment: Ah ok. Why the data is in a bad format? Thank you

Comment: How can I use a better format? If I use your first code, I get {'Minnesota-Dallas': ['NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', 5] and the other match. So I don't print all the scores for each match but only number (example 5)

Comment: @Takao貴男 the data in the database is in a bad format , a list shouldn't be stored like that, you should not duplicated information (the first 4 fields are duplicated)

Comment: Are you talking about ('Minnesota-Dallas', 'NHL', 8.1, 9, '15:00', [0, 1, 1, 5]) instead of the 4 repeats? Can you show me in your answer how to improve my format with the aim of being able to use your first code? I look forward to your kind reply to accept your reply with a green tick. Meanwhile I voted for you :)

Comment: @Takao貴男 regading the query again : i would say you need 2 SQL queries, one for the Next info, a second for the Results one, the second will give you the list

Comment: I accepted your answer. I fixed the format to use your first code. Thank you. Just one small curiosity regarding the difference in PERFORMANCE. If I use thousands and thousands of data in the database: 1. Is your second code less performant and slower in timing than your first code?.........2. Instead, your first code splits into two different types, so which one is more permanent (the one equivalent to row[1:6] or the one for better using unpacking)? I hope I would answer, because for me it is very important to know this about performance. Thank you

Comment: @Takao貴男 With the first format there is less data in the dabatase, so it's faster

Comment: Ok,but with the first format,to access the list of points grouped for each match (e.g. [0, 1, 1, 5]),i'll have to use sum(map(int,value[4].split("," )))/len(value[4]),otherwise I get an error.In this case I want to calculate the arithmetic mean and i need 0,1,1,5 taken individually.QUESTION: For best performance,i should use your first correctly formatted code which however uses sum(map(int,value[4].split(","))) / len(value[4])? Or I'd better use your second code with bad format which doesn't use sum(map(int,value[4].split(",")))/ len(value[4]) but just use sum(value[4] )/len(value[4])?

Comment: @Takao貴男 see my edit : you should have in fact 2 queries

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You're kind. What is the advantage of your new code with 2 queries compared to mine where I used Inner Join? I see that obviously the code for the dictionary has changed, but what's the benefit? Thank you

Comment: I tested your new code, but there is an error. The error is reported in the line of "q". I get this: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 14 supplied. How can this be solved? Thank you

Comment: @Takao貴男 That is clearly out of the scope of the question. I won't debug your code. Google the issue, search about it, print the variable in the line that fails, I stop to help you now